# How can I add placeholder using this Package react-native-picker-select

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, react-native-picker-select

I am using `react-native-picker-select` but by default it gives me the placeholder `Select an item...` how can I change this?

And add custom value. you can check this package by clicking [HERE](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-picker-select)

Comment: pass the props `placeholder={'custom value'}` in your picker

Comment: It will not excepting placeholder.